# Possible to balance unidic vs. unidic-neologd?

Tags: nlp, mecab

With the sentence "場所は多少わかりづらいんですけど、感じのいいところでした。"  (i.e. "It is a bit hard to find, but it is a nice place.") using `mecab` with `-d mecab-unidic-neologd` the first line of output is:

```
場所  バショ バショ 場所  名詞-固有名詞-人名-姓
```

I.e. it says "場所" is a person's surname. Using normal mecab-unidic it more accurately says the "場所" is just a simple noun.

```
場所  バショ バショ 場所  名詞-普通名詞-一般
```

My first question is has unidic-neologd replaced all the entries in unidic, or has it simply appended its 3 million proper nouns?

Then, secondly, assuming it is a merger, is it possibly to re-weight the entries, to prefer plain unidic entries a bit more strongly? I.e. I'd love to be getting 中居正広のミになる図書館 and SMAP each recognized as single proper nouns, but I also need it to see that 場所 is always going to mean "place" (except in the cases it is followed by a name suffix such as さん or 様, of course).

References: [unidic-neologd](https://github.com/neologd/mecab-unidic-neologd)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neologd merges with unidic (or ipadic), which is the reason it keeps "unidic" in the name. If an entry has multiple parts of speech, like 場所, which entry to use is chosen by minimizing cost across the sentence using part-of-speech transitions and, for words in the dictionary, the per-token cost.

If you look in the CSV file that contains neologd dictionary entries you'll see two entries for 場所:

```
場所,4786,4786,4329,名詞,固有名詞,一般,*,*,*,バショ,場所,場所,バショ,場所,バショ,固,*,*,*,*                              
場所,4790,4790,4329,名詞,固有名詞,人名,姓,*,*,バショ,場所,場所,バショ,場所,バショ,固,*,*,*,*
```

And in `lex.csv`, the default unidic dictionary:

```
場所,5145,5145,4193,名詞,普通名詞,一般,*,*,*,バショ,場所,場所,バショ,場所,バショ,混,*,*,*,*
```

The fourth column is the cost. A lower cost item is more likely to be selected, so in this case you can raise the cost for 場所 as a proper noun, though honestly I would just delete it. You can read more about fiddling with cost [here](http://www.mwsoft.jp/programming/munou/mecab_nitteretou.html) (Japanese).

If you want to weight all default unidic entries more strongly, you can modify the neolog CSV file to increase all weights. This is one way to create a file like that:

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{OFS=FS}{$4 = $4 * 100; print $0}' neolog.csv > neolog.fix.csv
```

You will have to remove the original csv file before building (see Note 2 below).

In this particular case, I think you should report this as a bug to the Neologd project.

---

Note 1: As mentioned above, since which entry is selected depends on the sentence as a whole, it's possible to get the non-proper-noun tag even with the default configuration. Example sentence:

```
お店の場所知っている？
```

---

Note 2: The way the neologd dictionary combines with the default unidic dictionary is based on a subtle aspect of the way Mecab dictionary builds work. Specifically, **all** CSV files in a dictionary build directory are used when creating the system dictionary. Order isn't specified so it's unclear what happens in the case of collisions.

This feature is mentioned in the Mecab documentation [here](https://taku910.github.io/mecab/dic.html) (Japanese).